# accessing multiple files

Tags: c#

My program is not looping through the files. The program correctly writes all the names of the files into 'list of files'. I then expect it to output the mean, min and max values of the list of data in each file. However, whenever it runs, it outputs the mean, min and max values for only one file. I think that the looping is not working very well.

I tried creating additional loop between textwriter tw3 and its closing bracket but this did not work. I also tried the same with tw4 but again it did not work. I am not sure whether the problem is due to the looping OR whether I am not using the right syntax to call each of the files in the folder. The whole code is below.

```
namespace Filereader_m_15062012
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string[] fileEntries;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            // create a list to insert the data into
            //put all the files in the root directory into array
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.csv");

            // Display all files.
            TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/listoffiles.txt");

            List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
            tw1.WriteLine("--- Files: ---");
            foreach (string path in fileEntries)
            {
                tw1.WriteLine(path);
            }

            tw1.Close();

            TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/errorlist.txt");
            foreach (string path in fileEntries)
            {  
                    string text = "";

                    // create a list to insert the data into
                    List<float> noise = new List<float>();

                    TextWriter tw3 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/rawdata.txt");

                    string file = path;

                    FileInfo src = new FileInfo(file);
                    TextReader reader = src.OpenText();
                    text = reader.ReadLine();

                    // while the text being read in from reader.Readline() is not null
                    while (text != null)
                    {
                        text = reader.ReadLine();

                        {
                            while (text != null)
                            {
                                text = reader.ReadLine();
                                if (text != null)
                                {
                                    string[] words = text.Split(',');
                                    noise.Add(Convert.ToSingle(words[3]));

                                    // write text to a file
                                    tw3.WriteLine(text);
                                    //foreach (string word in words)
                                    //{
                                    //    tw.WriteLine(word);
                                    //}
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        tw3.Close();


                        int count = 0;
                        float sum = 0;
                        float mean = 0;
                        float max = 0;
                        float min = 100;
                        List<string> means = new List<string>();
                        List<string> maximums = new List<string>();
                        List<string> minimums = new List<string>();

                        TextWriter tw4 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/noise.txt");

                            foreach (float ns in noise)
                            {
                                tw4.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ns));
                                count++;
                                sum += ns;
                                mean = sum / count;

                                float min1 = 0;


                                if (ns > max)
                                    max = ns;

                                else if (ns < max)
                                    min1 = ns;

                                if (min1 < min && min1 > 0)
                                    min = min1;
                                else
                                    min = min;
                            }

                            means.Add(Convert.ToString(mean));
                            maximums.Add(Convert.ToString(max));
                            minimums.Add(Convert.ToString(min));


                            TextWriter tw5 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/summarymeans.txt");
                            tw5.WriteLine("Mean Noise");
                            tw5.WriteLine("==========");
                            foreach (string m in means)
                            {
                                tw5.WriteLine("mote_noise: {0}", Convert.ToString(m));
                            }

                            tw5.Close();

                            TextWriter tw6 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/summarymaximums.txt");
                            tw6.WriteLine("Maximum Noise");
                            tw6.WriteLine("=============");
                            foreach (string m in maximums)
                            {
                                tw6.WriteLine("mote_noise: {0}", Convert.ToString(m));
                            }

                            tw6.Close();

                            TextWriter tw7 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/summaryminimums.txt");
                            tw7.WriteLine("Minimum Noise");
                            tw7.WriteLine("=============");
                            foreach (string m in maximums)
                            {
                                tw7.WriteLine("mote_noise: {0}", Convert.ToString(m));
                            }

                            tw7.Close();


                        tw4.Close();


                    }


                tw2.Close();
            }
        }        


        private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I will be very grateful for anybody help!!

Comment: This code could use quite a bit of cleanup... Any takers? :)

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to watch what it does?

Comment: You should be using the [FileInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx), it provides access to a lot of methods that would make your life easier.

[More Reading](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fileinfo).

It would make your loops a lot more readable and easier to follow as well.

Comment: @Amicable He is using the FileInfo class...

Comment: `text = reader.ReadLine(); while (text != null)                        text = reader.ReadLine(); while (text != null)                                text = reader.ReadLine(); if (text != null)` what this suppose to do?

Comment: Have you seen my answer Narh? @romkyns: I think I did just that...

Comment: Chibueze, thank you. The code nows works okay. Unfortunately the code does not output the min values correctly. It kinda repeats the max values for the min values.

Comment: Chibueze, i have fixed it and the results in the output now display corrcetly....Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your numbers (mean,mode,sum,count etc.) **inside** the for loop that iterates over your files, so they are reset for each file.

Initialize them outside the loop and it should work. (As others have pointed out there are other issues with the code as far as not looking very clean, but that is the underlying problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, your loops don't look right to me.  Why don't you try out something like this ("..." represent sections of your code that I didn't copy for the sake of brevity)?  Note that there is a single **while (text != null)** with a **text = reader.ReadLine();** at the end in stead of the multiple whiles and ifs in your example.

```
        foreach (string path in fileEntries)
        {
            ...
            string text = reader.ReadLine();

            // while the text being read in from reader.Readline() is not null
            while (text != null)
            {
                string[] words = text.Split(',');
                noise.Add(Convert.ToSingle(words[3]));

                // write text to a file
                tw3.WriteLine(text);
                //foreach (string word in words)
                //{
                //    tw.WriteLine(word);
                //}

                ...

                text = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            tw3.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Reniuz pointed out, when you are having this kind of problem, you should step through your code. In Visual studio, it is as difficult as setting a breakpoint (F9) where you want to start stepping through, and pressing F11 repeatedly once the debugger reaches the point.

In your case, however, the two errors are from your while loop and foreach loop. The correct version of the loops as well as the full code is shown below:

> **While loop should be:**

```
// while the text being read in from reader.Readline() is not null
while (text != null)
{
     string[] words = text.Split(',');
     noise.Add(Convert.ToSingle(words[3]));
     // write text to a file
     tw3.WriteLine(text);
     text = reader.ReadLine();
 }
```

> **Second loop should be:**

```
foreach (float ns in noise)
{
     tw4.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ns));
     count++;
     sum += ns;
     mean = sum / count;
     float min1 = 0;
     if (ns > max)
     max = ns;
     else if (ns < max)
         min1 = ns;
     if (min1 < min && min1 > 0)
         min = min1;
     means.Add(Convert.ToString(mean));
     maximums.Add(Convert.ToString(max));
     minimums.Add(Convert.ToString(min));
 }
```

> **And here goes the full code**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
              DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        // create a list to insert the data into
        //put all the files in the root directory into array
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.csv");

        // Display all files.
        TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/listoffiles.txt");

        List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
        tw1.WriteLine("--- Files: ---");
        foreach (string path in fileEntries)
        {
            tw1.WriteLine(path);
        }

        tw1.Close();

        TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/errorlist.txt");
        foreach (string path in fileEntries)
        {
            string text = "";

            // create a list to insert the data into
            List<float> noise = new List<float>();

            TextWriter tw3 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/rawdata.txt");

            string file = path;

            FileInfo src = new FileInfo(file);
            TextReader reader = src.OpenText();
            text = reader.ReadLine();

            // while the text being read in from reader.Readline() is not null
            while (text != null)
            {
                string[] words = text.Split(',');
                noise.Add(Convert.ToSingle(words[3]));

                // write text to a file
                tw3.WriteLine(text);
                text = reader.ReadLine();
            }

            tw3.Close();

            int count = 0;
            float sum = 0;
            float mean = 0;
            float max = 0;
            float min = 100;
            List<string> means = new List<string>();
            List<string> maximums = new List<string>();
            List<string> minimums = new List<string>();

            TextWriter tw4 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/noise.txt");

            foreach (float ns in noise)
            {
                tw4.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ns));
                count++;
                sum += ns;
                mean = sum / count;
                float min1 = 0;
                if (ns > max)
                    max = ns;

                else if (ns < max)
                    min1 = ns;

                if (min1 < min && min1 > 0)
                    min = min1;
                means.Add(Convert.ToString(mean));
                maximums.Add(Convert.ToString(max));
                minimums.Add(Convert.ToString(min));
            }

            TextWriter tw5 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/summarymeans.txt");
            tw5.WriteLine("Mean Noise");
            tw5.WriteLine("==========");
            foreach (string m in means)
            {
                tw5.WriteLine("mote_noise: {0}", Convert.ToString(m));
            }

            tw5.Close();

            TextWriter tw6 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/summarymaximums.txt");
            tw6.WriteLine("Maximum Noise");
            tw6.WriteLine("=============");
            foreach (string m in maximums)
            {
                tw6.WriteLine("mote_noise: {0}", Convert.ToString(m));
            }
            tw6.Close();

            TextWriter tw7 = new StreamWriter(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "/summaryminimums.txt");
            tw7.WriteLine("Minimum Noise");
            tw7.WriteLine("=============");
            foreach (string m in maximums)
            {
                tw7.WriteLine("mote_noise: {0}", Convert.ToString(m));
            }
            tw7.Close();
            tw4.Close();
        }


        tw2.Close();
 }
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to use `using` clauses instead of calling `Close` directly. Otherwise in case of an exception, the file remains open for an indeterminate amount of time, and future operations will fail randomly.

Comment: Yes of course, no need for modesty, I just focused on correcting the user's code rather than re-engineering it, If I was to rewrite it according to how I think it should be, it would be much more shorter and efficient...